# Determing whether dijit.dialog content has displayed

Tags: dojo

Does anyone know of a way to determine whether the content of a dijit.dialog has become visible to the user? As in if the content of the dialog has actually been displayed yet or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also an onShow event that you could connect to, or even set:

dijit.byId("dialog1").onShow = function(){console.log("hello world")};

Answer (score 1):

The function `onDownloadEnd()` is called when the [dialog](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.Dialog)'s download finishes.

You could [connect your own code](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojo.connect) to that event using `dojo.connect()`.